# GitLab-CI: run job only when a branch is made

Tags: gitlab-ci

In gitlab runner, I want to run job by separating branch creation and branch update.

(.yml example)

```
creat job:
  stage: create
  script:
    - echo 'branch checkout'
  only:
   - ????

update job:
  stage: deply
  script:
    - echo 'branch update'
  only:
   - branches
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to check `CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA`. If it is all zeros, then there is no previous commit for that ref. (It is also all zeros for a merge request.)

See [predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html).

Comment: thanx!! used this `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA == "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Comment: works well in combination with `changes`: https://gitlab.xfce.org/newhoa/catfish/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml#L23

Comment: @rdesgroppes link is not accessible :/